# Log in form and text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare the inputs of a login form (email and password ) to a text file content(the data are separated with a comma)

the text file looks like this :
email@gmail.com,password,name

my code that I have tried looks like this (the jTextField4 is for the email and jPasswordField1 is for the password) :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    boolean d = false;
    Scanner read = new Scanner("data.txt");
    read.useDelimiter(",");
    while(read.nextLine() !=null){
        String user = read.next();
        String pass = read.next();
        read.next();
        if(jTextField4.getText().equals(user)&&jPasswordField1.getText().equals(pass)){
            d=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(d)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password");
    }
}
```

but it keeps giving me errors

Comment: "it keeps giving me errors", it would come in handy if you were a wee bit more specific about that part.

Comment: post the error ouput also

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: this is the error i'm getting : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException......

Comment: run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
 at project_ihm.Login.jButton1ActionPerformed(Login.java:152)
 at project_ihm.Login$4.actionPerformed(Login.java:69)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at....

Comment: You are not doing anything with the return value of `read.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Scanner` incorrectly.
Read a line from the file.
Split it on the comma. This will give you an array of two elements where the first element is the username and the second element is the password.
Then compare each element with its corresponding text component.

The `while` loop should look like the following.

```java
boolean d = false;
while (read.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = read.nextLine();
    String[] parts = line.split(",");
    d = jTextField4.getText().equals(parts[0]) && jPasswordField1.getText().equals(parts[1]);
    if (d) {
        break;
    }
}
```

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) for class `java.util.Scanner`, method `nextLine` throws `NoSuchElementException` when there are no more lines to be read. Hence the `while` loop calls method `hasNextLine` in order to make sure that there is another line to be read.

Similarly, method `next` throws `NoSuchElementException` when there are no more "tokens" to be read.

You are getting the exception because you are not checking for the end of the file. So if the username and password entered by the user (via the GUI) does not exist in the file, the `while` loop tries to read past the end of the file and that causes `NoSuchElementException` to be thrown.

### EDIT

Here's how I would do it.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PwChecks implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static final String  CHECK = "Check";

    private JFrame  frame;
    private JPasswordField  passwordField;
    private JTextField  textField;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Path path = Paths.get("logindtl.txt");
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            String name = lines.filter(this::checkLine)
                               .map(line -> line.split(",")[2])
                               .findFirst()
                               .orElseThrow();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                          "Welcome " + name,
                                          "Login Successful",
                                          JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                          xIo,
                                          "ERROR",
                                          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException xNoSuchElement) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                          "Incorrect username or password",
                                          "ERROR",
                                          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        createAndDisplayGui();
    }

    private boolean checkLine(String line) {
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        String eMail = textField.getText();
        char[] letters = passwordField.getPassword();
        String password = new String(letters);
        return eMail.equals(fields[0])  &&  password.equals(fields[1]);
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Login");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createLogin(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text, int mnemonic) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton(CHECK, KeyEvent.VK_C));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createLogin() {
        JPanel login = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        login.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 5;
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 5;
        JLabel eMailLabel = new JLabel("eMail");
        login.add(eMailLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        textField = new JTextField(12);
        login.add(textField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        login.add(passwordLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(12);
        login.add(passwordField, gbc);
        return login;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new PwChecks());
    }
}
```

Here is file `logindtl.txt`

```
email@gmail.com,password,name
```

Here is a screen capture of the GUI.

[image: screen capture of GUI]

Comment: I have tried this solution but it always gives me the message that the username or password are incorrect, so basically the d is always false , i don't know the reason for that

Comment: @anes edit your question and post the code that you tried. And try to post a [mcve].

Comment: thank you so much, mate